# How to persist many objects to database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

My goal is to from json file create many java objects and then put  those object into my data base.I'm not sure how should put many objects in persist method, since persist method accept only entities.
I'm new to java and I actually don't know if this makes any sense and if this is achievable.
Json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Drama"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Horror"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mystery"
  }
]
```

Genre.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENRE")
public class Genre {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Genre() {}
    //setters getters
}
```

Main

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        EntityManager entityManager = null;

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

        try {

            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate-dynamic");

            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

            List<Genre> listGenre = objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:\\genre.json"), new TypeReference<List<Genre>>(){});


            entityManager.persist(???);

            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

            entityManager.close();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        } finally {
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I don't know what to put in "???" place to persist all those 3 objects from json file to db.

Comment: Loop through all the objects and persists each separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using "vanilla" `EntityManager`, you would have to loop through the collection:

```
listGenre.forEach(entityManager::persist);
```

When using spring, you could use `saveAll` method:

```
genreRepository.saveAll(listGenre);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.